# How to set loading progress while waiting for server response in react using typesctip

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to change the state of loading to false when the server responds but I don't know how to change the state when it happens. The response is in another component and the progress bar is in another one.
A simple example is like this:

```js
const Form: React.FC = () => {
   axios.get(someUrl).then(
   // changing a state to set the progress bar off
   ).catch(//catching error);
   ...
}
```

```js
const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  return (
    <MyProgressBar />
    ...
)}
```

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Header />
    <Form />
    ...
  );
}
```

I didn't mention any of the types here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the state in `Header` but want to control it from `Form`. One component cannot change the state of its peer.

## Fix

Move the state one level up, i.e. move it into `App`. And then you can change it from `Form` and read it in `Header` etc.